# Animate, video file problem.

Tags: animation, video

I have a function f(z,t) and I would like to animate it and also create a video file. For animation I do the following;

```
 Res1 = Sin[z t];
    vid = Animate[
    Plot[Res1, {z, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}], {t, 0, 1/3}];
    Print[vid];
```

This is not working, I am just getting a blank animation. When I do;

```
vid = Animate[
Plot[Sin[z t], {z, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}], {t, 0, 1/3}];
Print[vid];
```

this is working. I don't see why the first version is not working.

I also would like to save this animation as a movie. I don't think I can directly save that as a movie, but I found this;

```
frame[t_]:=ArrayPlot[Table[Sin[z t],{z,1,2}]];
frames=ParallelTable[frame[t],{t,0,1/3}];
Export["1stvid.mov",frames];
```

And I get an error. I am a little lost, I appreciate it some guidance.

Comment: the last error is unrelated to animation, your `ArrayPlot` expression is just wrong. (Its not even clear how to fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a scoping issue. You need to add arguments to `Res1` so that `z` and `t` have the same meaning inside the Animate

```
Res1[z_, t_] = Sin[z t];
vid = Animate[
  Plot[Res1[z, t], {z, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}], {t, 0, 1/3}]
```

[image]

**Click** on image above.

Export `vid` in whatever desired format.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to just generate frames and Export:

```
frames = Table[
   Plot[Sin[z t], {z, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}],
   {t, 0, 1/3, 1/60}];
Export["test.avi", frames]
```

This lets us control exactly how many frames are generated, while `Animate` figures that automatically.